# How do you store redundant data without creating extra tables?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Most of the data in each of my tables (Car, Truck, SUV, Jeep, Semi, and Motorcycle) looks the same but there isn't enough data to warrant creating tables for each field. That would pretty much be creating fifty tables, each with five or six records.

I guess you could store the defaults once somewhere and then provide a table with overrides. But if I do that I'm not sure where to put the default values since that sounds like it would be a table for each vehicle type with just one record each.

What I'm currently doing it just storing the redundant data because that makes working with the database so much easier. But are there any best practices I could use for storing this type of data in a relational database?

Here is an example:

Boat

```
'Cool Boat Company', 1, 'Bose® Premium Sound', '3 MegaStrong® Sails', '16,000 lbs', '30ft', '40ft', .05, 'USA', 'Gas', 90
'Cool Boat Company', 1, 'Bose® Premium Sound', '3 MegaStrong® Sails', '16,500 lbs', '35ft', '40ft', .05, 'USA', 'Gas', 90
'Cool Boat Company', 1, 'Bose® Premium Sound', '3 MegaStrong® Sails', '16,000 lbs', '37ft', '40ft', .05, 'USA', 'Gas', 90
'Cool Boat Company', 1, 'Bose® Premium Sound', '3 MegaStrong® Sails', '16,000 lbs', '39ft', '45ft', .05, 'USA', 'Gas', 90
'Cool Boat Company', 1, 'Bose® Premium Sound', '3 MegaStrong® Sails', '16,000 lbs', '41ft', '47ft', .05, 'USA', 'Gas', 90
'Cool Boat Company', 1, 'Bose® Premium Sound', '3 MegaStrong® Sails', '16,000 lbs', '45ft', '50ft', .05, 'USA', 'Gas', 90
```

And I've only got like fifteen boats. But I also have fifteen Cars, Trucks, SUVs, Jeeps, Semis, and Motorcycles.

My example data is not realistic but do you notice how most of the fields have the same data? I could break this into multiple tables but then I'd have a ton of tables with very little data and that level of complexity isn't really beneficial to me.

Comment: Edit your initial question to include examples of your table layouts, please.  And you should take a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Do you mean that your six tables are very similar in structure? Or that the rows within a given table are very similar? What do you mean by "redundant data"?

Comment: I added an example table. ...The rows within the table have very similar data. But the fields between the tables (Cars, Trucks, etc.) are almost all different.

Comment: @user875234 That's not necessarily redundant, though; it depends on what the functional dependencies are. Are there any FDs that violate Boyce-Codd normal form?

Comment: Hi. Time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design. Including normalization to higher NFs. This is too broad. Also it is not clear what you are asking. Give *some* design(s) holding the relevant data and ask a specific question in that context.

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely best practices for storing redundant data in databases.  It sounds like you don't have that much data, or that this project isn't big enough, or important enough, maybe to go into a deep dive of how best to store the data.  If it's a pet project and works, great.

There's one good formal recommendation you could implement to 'normalize' your data a bit better - if you're pretty sure most of the data in your columns for a table will always have the same data, or a few sets of data that go together, no need to include them in the base table.  For your boat example, if you've 12 boats that are all from Cool Boat Company, and they all have the same Bose sound, you can change that table to just store the lengths and the widths and capture all the other data as a 'type' of boat, and store the information about the 'type' in a different table like so:

The Boat table now looks like

> ### Boat
>
> TypeOfBoatId, Length, Width, Name##
>
> 1, '35ft', '40ft', 'The Rattlesnake!'
>
> 1, '37ft', '40ft', 'Big Bertha'
>
> 2, '4055ft', '2990ft', 'Water Palace'

and then you store all the redundant data in a new TypeOfBoat table

> ### TypeOfBoat
>
> TypeOfBoatId, Company, Sound, etc...
>
> 1,'Cool Boat Company', 'Bose® Premium Sound', etc...
>
> 2,'Bad Boy Boats','Computer Speakers', etc...

Then you can relate the Boat to the TypeOfBoat by the matching TypeOfBoatId's and not have all that redundant data, and you did it all with one extra table, not tons of extra tables.  So, the Boat table stores information that's generally different about each boat, and TypesOfBoats stores information that's generally the same about many boats.